# npm ERR! errno: -13, npm ERR! code: 'EACCES' when use npm install -g @vue/cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**in terminal I get this**
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/your username/.npm/_logs/2022-12-27T12_34_46_007Z-debug-0.log

**I found `npm install -g @vue/cli` in vue doc and I don't know why it don't work**

Comment: Answer pretty much written already: `The operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.` Check on how to get more rights in your OS. That question has probably been answered already.

Comment: in future please add info about error in title of question, it is better for searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it quick but in **WRONG WAY** writing

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

But it means that you giving too wide access for these scripts, that can be potentially vulnerable.

There are some ways to solve this problem:

### Change privileges do folder where you installing npm packages

From logs you can read that there is no access to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue`

So you can write

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
```

### Change place where global npm packages are installed

By commands:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
echo 'export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

This is recommended by npm docs https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory

### Use nvm instead of raw node

It is my preferred option

Installation and configuration of nvm is described here:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

Comment: `sudo` is indeed quite a bad approach.

Comment: We use sentinel and chown the usr/local is not permitted so stuck with NPM not working

Answer (score 0):

I was getting npm errno - 13 ( Permission denied.The operation was rejected by your operating system. It is likely one does not have the permissions to access the file as the current user. )

Follow below steps to solve this problem :

1. Add command to terminal : sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
   ( It changes the privileges to folder where you are installing npm packages. )

2.Change place where global npm packages are installed.

- mkdir ~/.npm-global
- npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
- echo 'export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
- source ~/.profile
- npm install -g @angular/cli

This will finally install angular to your local machine.

- By Vidhi Jayswal